# Is it possible to use ServiceStack Session and Caching without using the SS core?

Tags: servicestack

I came across an answer by Demis to a question similar to this on SO but I am not able to find the it now. I might need to use the Session and Caching with the Redis Client but not the core SO but I am not sure how feasible that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you need ServiceStack.Common, ServiceStack.Interface and ServiceStack.Text in order to user ServiceStack.Redis.

If you want your own Redis Client for Session and Caching you might use [one of the existing .Net Redis Client](http://redis.io/clients) or build your needs above them.

But a reference to SS Common, Interface and Text is a small price and you get a lot of additional useful stuff.